# What is the purpose of each of the memory locations, stack, heap, etc? (lost in technicalities)

Tags: memory

Ok, I asked the difference between Stackoverflow and bufferoverflow yesterday and almost getting voted down to oblivion and no new information.

So it got me thinking and I decided to rephrase my question in the hopes that I get reply which actually solves my issue.

So here goes nothing.

I am aware of four memory segments(correct me if I am wrong). The code, data, stack and heap. Now AFAIK the the code segment stores the code, while the data segment stores the data related to the program. What seriously confuses me is the purpose of the stack and the heap!

From what I have understood, when you run a function, all the related data to the function gets stored in the stack and when you recursively call a function inside a function, inside of a function... While the function is waiting on the output of the previous function, the function and its necessary data don't pop out of the stack. So you end up with a stack overflow. (Again please correct me if I am wrong)

Also I know what the heap is for. As I have read someplace, its for dynamically allocating data when a program is executing. But this raises more questions that solves my problems. What happens when I initially initialize my variables in the code.. Are they in the code segment or in the data segment or in the heap? Where do arrays get stored? Is it that after my code executes all that was in my heap gets erased? All in all, please tell me about heap in a more simplified manner than just, its for malloc and alloc because I am not sure I completely understand what those terms are!

I hope people when answering don't get lost in the technicalities and can keep the terms simple for a layman to understand (even if the concept to be described is't laymanish) and keep educating us with the technical terms as we go along. I also hope this is not too big a question, because I seriously think they could not be asked separately!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What and where are the stack and heap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*What is the stack for?*

Every program is made up of functions / subroutines / whatever your language of choice calls them. Almost always, those functions have some local state. Even in a simple for loop, you need somewhere to keep track of the loop counter, right? That has to be stored in memory somewhere.

The thing about functions is that the other thing they almost always do is *call other functions*. Those other functions have their own local state - their local variables. You don't want your local variables to interfere with the locals in your caller. The other thing that has to happen is, when FunctionA calls FunctionB and then has to do something else, you want the local variables in FunctionA to still be there, and have their same values, when FunctionB is done.

Keeping track of these local variables is what the stack is for. Each function call is done by setting up what's called a *stack frame*. The stack frame typically includes the return address of the caller (for when the function is finished), the values for any method parameters, and storage for any local variables.

When a second function is called, then a new stack frame is created, pushed onto the top of the stack, and the call happens. The new function can happily work away on its stack frame. When that second function returns, its stack frame is popped (removed from the stack) and the caller's frame is back in place just like it was before.

So that's the stack. So what's the heap? It's got a similar use - a place to store data. However, there's often a need for data that lives longer than a single stack frame. It can't go on the stack, because when the function call returns, it's stack frame is cleaned up and boom - there goes your data. So you put it on the heap instead. The heap is a basically unstructured chunk of memory. You ask for x number of bytes, and you get it, and can then party on it. In C / C++, heap memory stays allocated until you explicitly deallocate. In garbage collected languages (Java/C#/Python/etc.) heap memory will be freed when the objects on it aren't used anymore.

To tackle your specific questions from above:

*What's the different between a stack overflow and a buffer overflow?*

They're both cases of running over a memory limit. A stack overflow is specific to the stack; you've written your code (recursion is a common, but not the only, cause) so that it has too many nested function calls, or you're storing a lot of large stuff on the stack, and it runs out of room. Most OS's put a limit on the maximum size the stack can reach, and when you hit that limit you get the stack overflow. Modern hardware can detect stack overflows and it's usually doom for your process.

A buffer overflow is a little different. So first question - what's a buffer? Well, it's a bounded chunk of memory. That memory could be on the heap, or it could be on the stack. But the important thing is you have X bytes that you know you have access to. You then write some code that writes X + more bytes into that space. The compiler has probably already used the space beyond your buffer for other things, and by writing too much, you've overwritten those other things. Buffer overruns are often not seen immediately, as you don't notice them until you try to do something with the other memory that's been trashed.

Also, remember how I mentioned that return addresses are stored on the stack too? This is the source of many security issues due to buffer overruns. You have code that uses a buffer on the stack and has an overflow vulnerability. A clever hacker can structure the data that overflows the buffer to overwrite that return address, to point to code in the buffer itself, and that's how they get code to execute. It's nasty.

*What happens when I initially initialize my variables in the code.. Are they in the code segment or in the data segment or in the heap?*

I'm going to talk from a C / C++ perspective here. Assuming you've got a variable declaration:

int i;

That reserves (typically) four bytes on the stack. If instead you have:

char *buffer = malloc(100);

That actually reserves two chunks of memory. The call to malloc allocates 100 bytes on the heap. But you also need storage for the pointer, buffer. That storage is, again, on the stack, and on a 32-bit machine will be 4 bytes (64-bit machine will use 8 bytes).

*Where do arrays get stored...???*

It depends on how you declare them. If you do a simple array:

char str[128];

for example, that'll reserve 128 bytes on the stack. C never hits the heap unless you explicitly ask it to by calling an allocation method like malloc.

If instead you declare a pointer (like buffer above) the storage for the *pointer* is on the stack, the actual data for the array is on the heap.

*Is it that after my code executes all that was in my heap gets erased...???*

Basically, yes. The OS will clean up the memory used by a process after it exits. The heap is a chunk of memory in your process, so the OS will clean it up. Although it depends on what you mean by "clean it up." The OS marks those chunks of RAM as now free, and will reuse it later. If you had explicit cleanup code (like C++ destructors) you'll need to make sure those get called, the OS won't call them for you.

*All in all, please tell me about heap in a more simplified manner than just, its for malloc and alloc?*

The heap is, much like it's name, a bunch of free bytes that you can grab a piece at a time, do whatever you want with, then throw back to use for something else. You grab a chunk of bytes by calling malloc, and you throw it back by calling free.

Why would you do this? Well, there's a couple of common reasons:

1. You don't know how many of a thing
   you need until run time (based on
   user input, for example). So you
   dynamically allocate on the heap as
   you need them.
2. You need large data structures. On
   Windows, for example, a thread's
   stack is limited by default to 1
   meg. If you're working with large
   bitmaps, for example, that'll be a
   fast way to blow your stack and get
   a stack overflow. So you grab that
   space of the heap, which is usually
   much, much larger than the stack.

*The code, data, stack and heap?*

Not really a question, but I wanted to clarify. The "code" segment contains the executable bytes for your application. Typically code segments are read only in memory to help prevent tampering. The data segment contains constants that are compiled into the code - things like strings in your code or array initializers need to be stored somewhere, the data segment is where they go. Again, the data segment is typically read only.

The stack is a writable section of memory, and usually has a limited size. The OS will initialize the stack and the C startup code calls your main() function for you. The heap is also a writable section of memory. It's reserved by the OS, and functions like malloc and free manage getting chunks out of it and putting them back.

So, that's the overview. I hope this helps.

Comment: How are global variables handled... Aren't they stored in data segment ?

Comment: Whoa that was a really long read, but it definitely helps... will need to go through it a couple of times for it to completely sink in, but that is definitely answered quite a few questions! Will revert back with doubts here as and when they come to mind :) Thanks. +1

Comment: Where global variables are stored really varies by OS, loader, and compiler. The C memory model doesn't really have a concept of "data segment", that's part of the linker / os loader. They could be stored in the data segment. They could be stored at the very bottom of the stack before the stack frame of main. They could be on the heap somewhere. For the purposes of your application you don't really care.

Answer (score 2):

With respect to stack...  This is precicely where the parameters and local variables of the functions / procedures are stored.  To be more precise, the params and local variables of the currently executing function is only accessible from the stack... Other variables that belong to chain of functions that were executed before it will be in stack but will not be accessible until the current function completed its operations.

With respect global variables, I believe these are stored in data segment and is always accessible from any function within the created program.

With respect to Heap... These are additional memories that can be made allotted to your program whenever you need them (malloc or new)...  You need to know where the allocated memory is in heap (address / pointer) so that you can access it when you need. Incase you loose the address, the memory becomes in-accessible, but the data still remains there. **Depending on the platform and language this has to be either manually freed by your program (or a memory leak occurs) or needs to be garbage collected.**   Heap is comparitively huge to stack and hence can be used to store large volumes of data (like files, streams etc)...  Thats why Objects / Files are created in Heap and a pointer to the object / file is stored in stack.

Comment: Thanks this is byfar the simplest way I have seen someone put it :) BTW is there a heap overflow too?

Comment: The "heap overflow" is usually called "out of memory".

Answer (score 0):

In terms of C/C++ programs, the data segment stores static (global) variables, the stack stores local variables, and the heap stores dynamically allocated variables (anything you `malloc` or `new` to get a pointer to). The code segment only stores the machine code (the part of your program that gets executed by the CPU).